# Как запретить выполнение маршрута в Laravel по условию?

Tags: laravel, route

Следующая ситуация. Допустим у нас есть таблица оплат, и есть интерфейс по удалению записей в этой таблице. Но есть правило - можно удалять только те записи, которые добавлены час назад и более, и поле `paid` равно нулю.

**Вопрос**

Как запретить в интерфейсе такое удаление - я знаю. Но как мне запретить, если пользователь решит исполнить данный маршрут из строки адреса в браузере?

Какие подходы/механизмы в Laravel 8-10 для таких случаев обычно применяют?

Comment: Это примерно то же самое. Если ты скажешь такое. Как мне запретиь пользователя не удалять чюжие посты. Например если он сделает запрос из `postman`.
Все действия которые нужно тем или иным причинам запретиь можно использовать `Laravel Gates`.
Подробно посмотри в доке. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization

Answer (score -1):

Можно просто в контроллере сделать проверку при удалении:

```
if($item->created_at->diffInHours(now()) >= 1 && $item->paid == 0)
{
    $item->delete();
}
```